# How can I animate radial symmetric object?

Tags: modeling, animation

I want to make some kind or door animation for my unity project
and I have hard time animating and putting in keyframes.

I saw this tutorial on youtube and followed the steps.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GdiOhqi_XY

now I want to animate them, but It doesn't work.

right now ovelapping of objects doen't matter. I just want to animate my gate as if opening and closing.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use displace modifier or shape key.
method 1:displace modifier

[image]

change the value or insert keyframe.

---

method 2:shape key

[image]

select the object and press the add button twice.

[image]

go to edit mode select all and move it.

[image]

[image]

exit edit mode and change the value or insert keyframe.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!!! I will try it out. thank you for quick solution